# COGNOS: Convert SQL date prompt to date prompt in Cognos

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting, prompt, cognos

I currently have a problem to convert an SQL date prompt in Cognos. 
I would like to rebuild a SQL-Query into Cognos Report Studio 10.2.

In my SQL-Query I have implemented two prompts. The first one:

**SQL:** `where :date between DATE1 and DATE2`

I can solve this with following function in Cognos:

**COGNOS**:

```
where TO_DATE (#sq(prompt ( 'date_prompt', 'date' ))#, 'YYYY-MM-DD') between DATE1 and DATE2
```

but now I have problems with the following prompt where i have to convert der date into char and afterwards into number:

**SQL:**

```
where PART in (299912, to_number(to_char(:date, 'YYYYMM')))
```

I have tried following function:

**COGNOS:**

```
where PART in (299912, to_number(to_char(TO_DATE (#sq(prompt ( 'date_prompt', 'date' ))#, 'YYYYMM'))))
```

But i got following Error:

> UDA-SQL-0107 General exception error during the operation "open result".
>   ORA-01843 No valid month

Comment: Please clarify whether you're using the same input value for both these calls

Comment: Hello APC, i am using the same input value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a macro already, just make it do the work.

```
#
timestampmask(prompt('StartDate','timestamp'),'YYYYMM')
#
```

Comment: Hello Daniel, at least i dont get any error now. But if i use the following statement WHERE PART in (202002,(#
timestampmask(prompt('StartDate','timestamp'),'YYYYMM')#))  and i choose 10th March 2020 in the date prompt i got as result only 202002.

Comment: I am using 11.1.5 and the expression works fine,  if the month always one behind for you?  Meaning if you chose April do you get 3 instead of 4?

Comment: I am using 10.2. No its not behind - as you see i am using PART in (202002,(# timestampmask(prompt('StartDate','timestamp'),'YYYYMM')#))

So i expect two values one i put in by myself (202002) and then the value from the date prompt. But now i only got 202002 as output :/

Comment: Ah OK I understand now,  it does not seem to like the hard-coded and prompt value together in the in clause.  I assume that running each as an = operator works?  I'll have another look at the in clause on my end.

Comment: I also tried to use only the prompt with = operator but than the output of the query is empty.

Comment: What does the where clause look like in the SQL?

Comment: It looks like this: 

Select PART from table1
where PART in (299912, to_number(to_char(:date, 'YYYYMM')))

Comment: Sorry,  you'll need to set the query property Use SQL Parameters to literal to see the actual value,  default is marker which is the date portion above.

Comment: I solved it now with this format WHERE PART in (299912, to_number(to_char(to_date(#prompt('test')#, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'YYYYMM')))

Thanks for your input mate :)